# QML left margin in RowLayout

Tags: listview, qml, margin

I have a listview with a delegate as separate qml file. Everything works fine except for the formatting in the respective line.

This is what I get actually

[image]

UserListDelegate.qml

```
Item {
    id: root
    height: configuration.getSize(Sizes.ListItemHeight)
    width: parent.width
    property int p_index
    property string p_name
    property string p_icon
    property bool p_selectable
    property bool p_isSelected: root.ListView.view.currentIndex == p_index
    property string p_color: configuration.getColor(p_selectable ? (p_isSelected ? Colors.ListItemSelected : Colors.ListItemDefault) : Colors.ListItemDisabled) 
    
    Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent; Layout.fillWidth: true; Layout.fillHeight: true; color: p_color
        RowLayout { anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter; 
            Image { anchors.leftMargin: 50; sourceSize.height: root.height * 0.6; source: "image://iconprovider/" + p_icon }
            Label { anchors.leftMargin: 50; text: p_name }
        }
        MouseArea{ anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: { root.ListView.view.currentIndex = p_index; } } 
    }
}
```

The icons should have a small border on the left. I try x: 50, anchors.leftMargin: 50 but all without a change. Between the three lines there should also be some space. How would I have to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get an error when using anchors in a layout. Use the attached property [Layout.leftMargin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#leftMargin-attached-prop).

```
RowLayout {
    spacing: 0

    Rectangle { width: 40; height: 40; color: "red"; Layout.leftMargin: 20 }
    Rectangle { width: 40; height: 40; color: "green" }
}
```

About the space between the items I assume you are using the `ListView` from your previous question, you should use [spacing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-listview.html#spacing-prop). The space between your header and the `ListView` needs to be done manual with an `Item` that has `height` set as the header isn't managed by the `ListView`.

**Note:** `ListView` has a [header](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-listview.html#header-prop) property which you can use.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I have not thought about layout - works fine. The reference to header property is great -works with the same delegate component

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to add additional 50px margins in your `RowLayout` is via additional `Item { Layout.preferredWidth: 50 }`, e.g.

```
    RowLayout {
        Item { Layout.preferredWidth: 50 }
        Image { sourceSize.height: root.height * 0.6; source: "image://iconprovider/" + p_icon }
        Item { Layout.preferredWidth: 50 }
        Label { text: p_name }
    }
```